# Use of bitshift operator in JavaScript find() polyfill

Tags: javascript, arrays, bit-shift

Can anyone explain why the `>>>` bitshift operator is required in [the Array.find() polyfill shown on the MDN website](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find#Polyfill):

```
....
var list = Object(this);
var length = list.length >>> 0;
....
```

I understand it is sometimes used as an ugly way to truncate floating point values to integers, but that doesn't seem to be the case here, since the `length` value of `list` would be an integer anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I understand it is sometimes used as an ugly way to truncate floating point values to integers

Not exactly. `value >>> 0` is the only exposed way to use the [ToUint32(value)](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-touint32) abstract operation.

[Arrays](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array-exotic-objects) have the invariant that their length must be a Uint32 value:

> Every Array object has a **length** property whose value is always a
>   nonnegative integer less than 2<sup>32</sup>.

That's why the spec uses ToUint32 all over the place in array method definitions. Polyfills use `>>> 0` instead of ToUint32 because ToUint32 is not exposed to JS code.

You need to use ToUint32 because you can't know what `this` will be in an array method, it can be a non-array object or even a primitive. Otherwise `Object(this)` wouldn't be necessary neither.

Answer (score 1):

You can `apply` the `Array.prototype.find()` method to any object with properties of integers >= 0 and with a `length` property. Then it might be safe to truncate it's `length` property first into an integer in case the `length` property of our exotic array is a calculated property and not a perfect integer. Since `Math.trunc()` is an ES6 functionality it fits to the nature of a Polyfill to use the `>>>` operator with a `0` argument.

```js
var obj = {7:"g", 1:"b", 2:"c", 0: "a", length: 4.7},
    val = [].find.call(obj, v => v === "c");
console.log(val);
```